# How to test a method which calls another method in another class without Mockingn frameworks

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I've been trying to get this scenario tested but I can't find a good way to test it. So this method under test creates a new Object of certain custom type which invokes a method afterwards.Now during debugging when my code reaches to this point it detects new object being created but when it goes into the method it blows up because certain fields are not initialized. There is no relationship between the Class I am testing the and the class for which my test is failing. Without any Mocking framework is there a way to test this. I cannot change the source code too. If it is a bad code can I still test it.

```
class DocuSigRESTProvider{
 public IDocumentSet sendDocuments() {
 /// code...
 ITransformer transformer = new SendDocumentsRESTTransformer();
 ITransformerResult result = transformer.transformRequest(args);
 }
}
```

When the code goes into transformrequest() it blows up because of certain field. It always creates a new so even if in my test class I create an instance of SendDocumentRESTTransformer it won'y find that particular field to be initialized at run time.

JUnit

```
private SendDocumentsRESTTransformer sendDocumentRESTTransfomer;
private ITransformerResult iTransformerResult;   

sendDocumentRESTTransfomer = mock( SendDocumentsRESTTransformer.class );
iTransformerResult = mock( ITransformerResult.class );

@Test
public void testSendDocuments() throws Exception {
    DocusignRESTProvider docusignRestProvider = new DocusignRESTProvider();
    docusignRestProvider.setLoggingHandler( iloggingHandler );
    docusignRestProvider.setDocumentManager( iDocumentManager );
    docusignRestProvider.setConfiguration( iProviderConfiguration );
    docusignRestProvider.setManager( idocTranManager );
    docusignRestProvider.setEmailProcessor( emailProcessor );

    List<IDocumentDto> iDocumentDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
    iDocumentDtoList.add( iDocumentDto );

    List<IDocument> iDocumentList = new ArrayList<>();
    iDocumentList.add( iDocument );

    when( restProvider.loadDocuments( iClientUserDto, iDocumentSet ) ).thenReturn( iDocumentDtoList );
    when( iDocumentSet.getDocuments() ).thenReturn( iDocumentList );
    when( restProvider.validateDocs( anyListOf( IDocument.class ), anyListOf( IDocumentDto.class ) ) ).thenReturn( iDocumentDtoList );
    PowerMockito.whenNew( SendDocumentsRESTTransformer.class ).withAnyArguments().thenReturn( sendDocumentRESTTransfomer );
    when( sendDocumentRESTTransfomer.transformRequest( any( ITransformerArgs.class ) ) ).thenReturn( iTransformerResult );

    iDocumentSet = docusignRestProvider.sendDocuments( iClientUserDto, iDocumentSet );
    assertNotNull( iDocumentSet );
}
```

Is this code testable?

Comment: Good testing will mock it and only test that one function. You don't wanna start going through multiple methods in testing.

Comment: I tried that too but I don't get a mocked object. I tried using PowerMockito's WhenNew() but it is not giving me a mocked object to just test this class in isolation.

Comment: Do you want to write a unit-test for it or to debug?

Comment: Could you post the unit test that you tried?

Comment: I've posted the test above. Where Iam using PowerMock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `setter` method to inject your external dependency.
Something like this.

```
class DocuSigRESTProvider{
 private ITransformer transformer = new SendDocumentsRESTTransformer();

 public IDocumentSet sendDocuments() {
   /// code...
   ITransformerResult result = transformer.transformRequest(args);
 }
  //package level method
 void setTransformer(ITransformer transformer) {
    this.transformer = transformer
 }
}
```

And then you can inject a `stub` object from your test class.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
  DocuSigRESTProvider docusignRestProvider = new DocuSigRESTProvider();
  docusignRestProvider.setTransformer(new SendDocumentsRESTTransformerStub());

  //...rest of test code.
}

private class SendDocumentsRESTTransformerStub extends SendDocumentsRESTTransformer {
  //... Override methods.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but it's working now using PowerMockito.

Comment: Sure. Your idea to mock this dependency without any library is better. This makes your code more flexible

Comment: You are right, but this is a legacy code. One change changes everything. :)

Answer (score 1):

In general code has to be written in a certain way to be unit testable. You can't just take any (arbitrary) piece of code and unit test it in a clean way.

So, you should adhere some conventions/follow some practices. The provided code snippet doesn't really follow these practices so you're forced to use PowerMock, which should be used (if at all) only if there is absolutely no other choice. Personally I try to avoid using power mock as much as I can.

The first rule of thumb is to use dependency injection and not create objects within your method with a `new` keyword.

So let's slightly change your code:

```
class DocuSigRESTProvider{
  private ITransformer transformer;

  public DocuSigRESTProvider(ITransformer transformer) {
     this.transformer = transformer;
  }

  public IDocumentSet sendDocuments() {
     /// code...
     ITransformerResult result = transformer.transformRequest(args);
  }
}
```

So what did we gain actually? A lot: the `DocuSigRESTProvider`class doesn't deal with creating an ITransformer implementation (indeed why should it bother, it should rather get an interface and work against it). The interface implementation is **injected** from outside (read about constructor injection, setter injection and so forth, I won't dive into dependency injection as it's a broad topic on its own).

So the test that is supposed to check what's written in "code" section (after all you check a `sendDocuments` method) is not supposed to create any more until you come to the last line which is a transformer invocation.

Now you do really want to mock/stub a transformer but this time (and this is a significant improvement!) you should mock the interface and not a real implementation. With this approach you can use EasyMock/Mockito - both of them can create mocks for interface or even craft your own "fake" implementation if you want.